# Remove digits from file

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create new file without digits in strings

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "input1.txt"
    putStr (process contents)

check = if isDigit x
            x = "a"

process :: String -> String         
process = map check
```

but getting that error: "Syntax error in expression (unexpected symbol "process")". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use an `if`-`then` without using an `else`. You should write it as `check x = if isDigit x then 'a' else x`. You use Haskell in an imperative way, but Haskell is a *functional* language.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, `if` “statements” are actually expressions and must return a value. So you need to have an else block.

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

check x = if isDigit x then 'a' else x

process :: String -> String
process = map check

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "input1.txt"
    putStr (process contents)
```

Also, if you want to *remove* the digits, then `filter` is a better option than using `map check`. So you can refactor process to

```
process :: String -> String
process = filter (not . isDigit)
```